# How to implicitly convert class template object when passing as argument to function template?

Tags: c++, class, templates, casting, implicit-conversion

Considering the following small code snippet:

```
template <typename T>
class A{
public:
    A() { };
    ~A() { };
    // ...
    template <typename outT = T> operator std::vector<outT>(){ /* implicit/explicit cast to std::vector */ }    
};

template <typename T = float>
void myFunc(const std::vector<T>& _arg){
    printf("myFunc\n");
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) { 
    A<int> foo;
    myFunc(foo);
}
```

When trying to compile, I get the error

```
template argument deduction/substitution failed: [...]  ‘A<int>’ is not derived from ‘const std::vector<T>’
```

While, on the other hand, if `myFunc` is not a template, it will compile and run just fine. I assume the error is caused by the fact that since `myFunc` accepts multiple vector types as argument, the compiler does not know to what type it should convert `foo` to. However, shouldn't the default template values be used as fallback in such case? Is there an alternative way to be able to pass an object of class `A` to `myFunc`?

Comment: No implicit conversion will happen with a template function.  You have to manually cast, if you want it converted to something it is not.

Comment: please provide the code that causes the error (see also [mcve]). Its not  clear how `myFunc` and `A` are related.

Comment: @NathanOliver If `myFunc` is untemplated and takes, for instance, an `std::vector<float>` as argument, `foo` is cast implicitely. Shouldn't the default value for `myFunc` template (`float`)  be used then?

Comment: @user463035818 I've added a small `main()` to reproduce the error. `A` and `myFunc` aren't related.

Comment: The default argument is irrelevant because the entire conversion template is a red herring. You can declare it as `operator std::vector<T>()` and you will still get the same error. You can make the entire class `A` non-template either andbut makes no difference, still the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Implicit conversions are not considered when attempting to deduce template parameters. Since `A<int>` cannot match `const std::vector<T>`, the `myFunc` template is not a viable candidate. This remains true even if you [explicitly instantiate](https://godbolt.org/z/mFtT_Y) it beforehand (and even if the conversion operator is [not templated](https://godbolt.org/z/WBPisc)).

For overload resolution, implicit conversion *are* considered, which is why the non-templated version works. The templated version never gets to participate because it is not a viable candidate.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that template argument deduction does not consider implicit conversions, so when you write `myFunc(foo)` the compiler is unable to determine a type for T.  And that's really the end of the story.

See [Template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) on C++ reference.

Walter E. Brown gave a fantastic talk about how function templates work (including why you should call them *function templates* and not *templatized functions*) at CppCon2018 which I highly recommend.

See "[C++ Function Templates: How Do They Really Work?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NIDEjY5ywqU)" on youtube.